# Объясните постановку знаков препинания.

Tags: пунктуация

Есть, правда, у других народов словари, превышающие словарь Даля совершенством отделки, богатством историко-литературного материала и так далее; но трудно найти другой словарь, совмещающий в себе столько материала, почерпнутого одним только лицом из живого, разговорного языка известного народа.

Comment: Предложите свое объяснение или задайте конкретный вопрос  о том, что Вы не можете объяснить.

Comment: Мне нужно понять почему стоят эти препинания в определённом месте. Например:...словари, превышающие словарь Даля. (в данном случае стоит запятая перед "словари" т.к. после стоит причастие).Также нужно объяснить расположение всех остальные препинаний.

Comment: @Фурия мы можем проверить выполненное вами задание, но не будем выполняет его за вас. Если вам не понятны какие-то места, обозначьте их, но не может же быть всё задание целиком непонятно! (Выше вы привели собственное обоснование — так поступите так же и с другими знаками пунктуации, добавьте свои объяснения в текст вопроса — и мы вам поможем.)